# Swagger OpenApi dynamic query param name using annotation for Spring custom resolver

Tags: swagger, openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm trying to figure out how to indicate to `SpringDoc` `OpenApi` that a custom object is being generated using `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` which intercepts some incoming request parameters and creates an object out of it. The concept is actually just the same as Spring does with `@Pageable`.

Here's some part of my custom object:

```
class FlightRequestHandlerMethodArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
FlightRequestHandlerMethodArgumentResolver() {
}

@Override
boolean supportsParameter(final MethodParameter parameter) {
    return FlightRequest.class.equals(parameter.getParameterType());
}

@Override
Object resolveArgument(
        final MethodParameter parameter,
        final ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
        final NativeWebRequest webRequest, final WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
    final Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = webRequest.getParameterMap()
    // query param names are configurable
    // implementation about finding query param names is ommited
    return new FlightRequest(parameterMap)
}
```

`FlightRequest` class:

```
public class FlightRequest {

@Parameter(name = "startDate")
private final LocalDate startDate;

@Parameter(name = "endDate")
private final LocalDate endDate;

FlightRequest (LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
    this.submissionStartDate = submissionStartDate;
    this.submissionEndDate = submissionEndDate;
}
```

Controller that uses `FlightRequest` with default query param names:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/flights", method = RequestMethod.GET)
Flights flights(FlightRequest flightRequest, HttpServletResponse response) {
    return flightSearchService.retrieveFlights(flightRequest);
}
```

Controller that uses `FlightRequest` with custom query param names:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/current-flights", method = RequestMethod.GET)
Flights flights(@FlightRequestParams(fromDateParamName="current-flights-from", toDateParamName="current-flights-till) FlightRequest flightRequest, HttpServletResponse response) {
    return flightSearchService.retrieveFlights(flightRequest);
}
```

Like you see in the example above, each endpoint can override default query param names.
How can I indicate this to `Spring Doc`?

Comment: It's been a while now since this question is open. Please post it in the [Springdoc - issues](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues). If an issue is already open, do put it across in the comments to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not using here a spring annotation, but your own: @FlightRequestParams.

If, you really want the default values to be dynamically added, then you can write your own for your annotation [DelegatingMethodParameterCustomizer](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/blob/master/springdoc-openapi-data-rest/src/main/java/org/springdoc/data/rest/customisers/DataRestDelegatingMethodParameterCustomizer.java), for your annotation, as it's done for `@PageableDefault`.
Then declare it as a spring Bean, as [follow](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/blob/b664aa04af87486ca68c1fcf23022f13a58a7b77/springdoc-openapi-data-rest/src/main/java/org/springdoc/data/rest/SpringDocDataRestConfiguration.java#L98).

Or the simplest way, is to declare the parameter value using `@Parameter` annotation. You can see an example of [PageableAsQueryParam](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/blob/5842104a4d4d4d68d2744eaa779afb29285b5f58/springdoc-openapi-common/src/main/java/org/springdoc/core/converters/models/PageableAsQueryParam.java).